# False behavior of Notification Snack bar in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

React admin delete update notification or snack bar is showing before getting response from the respective query form data-provider

**What it should be like**

when I hit the delete button the below toast notification should wait for the response from the graphql query defined in dataProvider and show the error in toast or snackbar below

**What is happening instead**

when I hit the delete button the below toast notification does not wait for the response from the graphql query defined in dataProvider and shows the `Elemnent is Deleted` in toast or snackbar below after that if the query got an `error` it shows them after `Elemnent is Deleted` toast this is wrong behavior.

Here is the proof:
https://streamable.com/rlef7y

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is configurable, here is a description of the logic of work: ["Optimistic Rendering and Undo"](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#optimistic-rendering-and-undo)

Comment: Thanks i did it as `mutationMode="pessimistic"` in edit that behavour has been gone from when i open the edit page of each row and delete it , but that thing is still happening when i delete from list by select the element not from the edit page.

Comment: For the DeleteButton button, this behavior also needs to be configured: <DeleteButton mutationMode="pessimistic" />

Comment: I  Solved this by



 `const PostBulkActionButtons = () => (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/* <BulkExportButton /> */}
      <BulkDeleteButton mutationMode="pessimistic" />
    </React.Fragment>
  );`


and call it in the props of `List` Components props as 


` bulkActionButtons={<PostBulkActionButtons />}`

Comment: For batch removal, there is also: <BulkDeleteWithConfirmButton mutationMode="pessimistic" />